# Spring Batch SQL Query with in clause

Tags: sql, spring-batch, in-clause

I am new to Spring batch.
I am currently developing a test project to learn Spring batch and I have run into an issue.
My requirement is that I need to query my oracle database to find the ids from one table and then pass those ids and get the details from other table for those ids. Currently I have roughly 300 ids.
I can get the ids but I am not sure how to pass those Ids in the Sql query in clause all at once to get the other fields which are stored in different table.
I am also open to other suggestions to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Nik

Answer (score 1):

> I can get the ids but I am not sure how to pass those Ids in the Sql query in clause all at once to get the other fields which are stored in different table

You can create a:

- first step (tasklet) that gets those IDs and puts them in the execution context
- second step (chunk-oriented) that reads those IDs from the execution context and use them in the `in` clause of the reader's query

Passing data between steps in explained in details in the [Passing Data to Future Steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) section of the reference documentation.

> My requirement is that I need to query my oracle database to find the ids from one table and then pass those ids and get the details from other table for those ids
>
> I am also open to other suggestions to solve this issue.

I suggest to use a common pattern called the [Driving Query Pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) because I think it is a good fit for your requirement. The idea is that the reader gets only the IDs and a processor asks for the details of each ID from other tables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In this case, should we pass a single ID to the reader's query at a time? - because unlike a JdbcTemplate, a JdbcCursorItemReader does not have a query method which can take list. Rather, it uses a PreparedStatementSetter.